# Sharepoint Client Object Model The property or field has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I have a C# program that manages Sharepoint lists using the Sharepoint Client Object Model. Occasionally  we will have server issues which will prevent the program from accessing the sharepoint server. I am using a helper class to run the ExecuteQuery method and have exception handling to continue to execute until there is no exception.

```
       private void ExecuteContextQuery(ref ClientContext siteContext)
    {
        int timeOut = 10000;
        int numberOfConnectionErrors = 0;
        int maxNumberOfRetry = 60;

            while (numberOfConnectionErrors < maxNumberOfRetry)
            {
                try
                {
                    siteContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {

                    numberOfConnectionErrors++;
                    Service.applicationLog.WriteLine("Unable to connect to the sharepoint site. Retrying in " + timeOut);
                    Service.applicationLog.WriteLine("Exception " + Ex.Message + " " + Ex.StackTrace);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeOut);
                    if (numberOfConnectionErrors == maxNumberOfRetry)
                    {
                        throw Ex;
                    }

                }
         }

    }
```

However I getting an error messages

> The property or field 'LoginName' has not been initialized.

and

> collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

The error messages seem to be related to methods where I call the Load method. here is an example of my code that calls the method above.

```
                List sharepointList = siteContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(this._listName);
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            items = sharepointList.GetItems(query);

            siteContext.Load(items);

            //siteContext.ExecuteQuery();
            ExecuteContextQuery(ref siteContext);
```

Do I need to reload the site context with every call to ExecuteQuery? Is that why I am seeing the error message above?

Here is the function I am using for getting the Login ID which is generating the error

```
    public String getLoginIDbyUserId(int userID)
    {
        ClientContext siteContext = getClientContextObject();
        User _getUser = siteContext.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(userID);

        siteContext.Load(_getUser);
        //siteContext.ExecuteQuery();
        ExecuteContextQuery(ref siteContext);

        String loginID = String.Empty;
        String formatedLoginID = String.Empty;
        loginID = _getUser.LoginName;
        if (loginID.Contains('|'))
        {

            formatedLoginID = loginID.Substring(loginID.IndexOf('|') + 1);

        }
        siteContext.Dispose();
        return formatedLoginID;
    }
```

Comment: it won't hurt to try.;)

Comment: please put your code, how you have used that `LoginName` property.

Comment: Hi @SantoshaEpili, the code has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to load **LoginName** property of user while loading user object. And after excutequery method, try to consume **LoginName** property of **User**

```
siteContext.Load(_getUser, u => u.LoginName);
```

And after this change your code should look like this

```
public String getLoginIDbyUserId(int userID)
    {
        ClientContext siteContext = getClientContextObject();
        User _getUser = siteContext.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(userID);

        siteContext.Load(_getUser, u => u.LoginName);
        //siteContext.ExecuteQuery();
        ExecuteContextQuery(ref siteContext);

        String loginID = String.Empty;
        String formatedLoginID = String.Empty;
        loginID = _getUser.LoginName;
        if (loginID.Contains('|'))
        {

            formatedLoginID = loginID.Substring(loginID.IndexOf('|') + 1);

        }
        siteContext.Dispose();
        return formatedLoginID;
    }
```

Comment: I know this thread is very old, but I wanted to say thanks. I got around to implementing it and it worked great.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, even after loading the properties explicitly. Most of the time it works fine but some times (may be when server is not responding) it throws "property not initialized" or "collection not initialized" exception.

Can you share the work around for this.

Thanks in advance.